# Deep Clone If List Item Has Another List

Tags: c#, asp.net, deep-copy

I m trying to clone generic list with clone extension.

```
List<Vehicle> newList = currentVehicleList.Clone().ToList();

public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T : ICloneable
{
    return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
}
```

I have Vehicle object implemented `ICloneable`

```
public class Vehicle : ICloneable
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string Plaka { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double FilledVolume { get; set; }
    public double DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public double IdleVolume
    {
        get { return this.Volume - this.FilledVolume; }
        set { }
    }
    public double FilledWeight { get; set; }
    public double IdleWeight {
        get { return this.WeightCapacity - this.FilledWeight; } 
        set{}
    }
    public decimal ConstantCost { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public bool IsRent { get; set; }
    public double AvgVelocity { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPerKilometer { get; set; }
    public double WeightCapacity { get; set; }
    public bool InProgress { get; set; }
    public List<Order> FilledOrders { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

the extension clone my list but the vehicle object has **FilledOrders** property typed `List<Order>` so clone does not perform for FilledOrders list.

```
public class Order : ICloneable
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public bool IsTwoWayDirection { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Product,int> OrderedProducts { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Product, int> ReOrderedProducts { get; set; }
    public Double DemandTotalWeigth { get; set; }
    public Double DemandTotalVolume { get; set; }
    public Double PickupTotalWeigth { get; set; }
    public Double PickupTotalVolume { get; set; }
    public double EarliestArrivedTime { get; set; }
    public double ArrivedTime { get; set; }
    //TODO :Timespana cevrilecek
    public Double AcceptStartDate { get; set; }
    public Double AcceptEndDate { get; set; }
    public Double ServiceTime { get; set; }
    //

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

What is the solution for clone if list item  has another list ?

Comment: Just... do it yourself. Write more code in `Clone()` to make a copy of the List. That's why you're implementing that function in the first place, y'know; so you can take care of stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Vehicle` class, just expand your `Clone()` function to clone the list:

```
public object Clone()
{
    Vehicle clone = this.MemberwiseClone();
    List<Order> clonedOrders = new List<Order>();
    foreach (Order order in this.FilledOrders)
        clonedOrders.Add((Order)order.Clone());
    clone.FilledOrders = clonedOrders;
    return clone;
}
```

That's the whole point of implementing IClonable, after all. Otherwise you could just call `MemberwiseClone()` on anything.

The Dictionary objects inside the `Order` class won't be cloned either, by the way, since they're also reference types. To fix that, the principle is the same: expand the `Clone()` function of `Order` and manually create copies of them in there. If it's necessary to clone even that one's `Product` items, implement `IClonable` in the `Product` class too and do the same there.

As long as there are no circular references, you can just keep implementing `IClonable` and fixing the reference types in the `Clone()` function.

Comment: Yes its solution for me. i tried it works.  ;Thanks @Nyerguds.

Comment: @erkandemir I edited the answer, btw. Not sure how `MemberwiseClone()` deals with those dictionaries inside the `Order` class. But as I said, the principle there is exactly the same.